# Android Circle Manipulation

Tags: android, animation, geometry, porter-duff

I have a PNG of a full circle. I would like to do an animation of the circle being drawn through each quadrant (as in it draws itself clockwise). How can i do this? anyone with an example?

Comment: What you're referring to would have little to do with the PNG itself, it would just be drawing/revealing an image in a clockwise animation.  I don't think you're going to have any luck, and should look into either making an animation out of it or drawing it with vectors.

Comment: Hi, Could you please share how you achieved this finally?

Comment: Read here to see how it was solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156674/android-gauge-animation-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do something with `Canvas.clipPath(Path)` in a custom view.

Answer (score 1):

Good sample code related to drawing arcs / semi circles is available on the Android Developer site [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Arcs.html).

For your specific case, I see two approaches.

One is to ditch the PNG file entirely and just draw the circle (best if there's nothing special about the circle:  It's just one color, etc).

If you definitely want to use the PNG file, then you can draw a background-colored, filled-in circle on top of that, and animate it in reverse (erasing itself counter-clockwise), which will reveal the circle in your PNG file as a result.