# Android Speedometer (Needle Gauge)

Tags: android, animation, 2d, tween

Creating a simple app that calculates the speed your going and displays it in a speedometer graphic. I can do all the speed calculations, gps calculations etc.. but i am not too sure about the animation. Does anyone have any good tutorials or examples on needle gauges other than the thermometer example out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably start with something like [this](http://atstechlab.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/gauge-and-dial-widget-for-android/).

Then when transitioning between values, do an animation where the needle gradually moves to the next value X units per unit of  time.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156674/android-gauge-animation-question) is also very similar to yours.

Answer (score 6):

I know, the post is quite old. But I had the same situation: there is no a good control for representing speed. I guess many people are facing this.

I've implemented SpeedometerView myself: a simple speedometer with needle and colored value ranges. Feel free to download!

https://github.com/ntoskrnl/SpeedometerView

[image]

This control was used in my app [CardioMood](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cardiomood.android).

The code is not optimized, but works. Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

Check here. It is my code. If you have any question please let me know.
Visit https://github.com/mucahitsidimi/GaugeView

You can implement Gauge to your project simply.

```
<com.sidimi.mucahit.gaugeview.GaugeView
android:id="@+id/gaugeView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

You can set width and height what ever you want to. It will calculate everything automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check the  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551295/simple-gauge-view-like-speedmeter-in-android/14466812?noredirect=1#comment26852940_14466812) i found for my case.

Big thanks to the owner Evelina Vrabie...

[image]