# Simple gauge view like speedmeter in android?

Tags: android, view, android-animation, android-custom-view, gauge

I want to have a simple gauge view where i will define the start value and the end value and have a pointer to show given variable value.

[image]

So i can show a given value like speedmeter. For example if my the value of a textView is 1300, then next to the textview i want to have this custom meter view animation like this!

It is possible? Any existing example code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Another one i found at [`Evelina Vrabie's blog`](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2012/08/android-gaugeview-library/), used it and worked perfect!

Look at [`Evelina Vrabie's GitHub`](https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView). 
It has a gauge library and some samples to interact with.

> Big thanks to the owner Evelina Vrabie!

---

[image]

However it is not working on XHDPI/Few versions of android devices (above 4). Problem is the text in gauge view.

Comment: Those this view still works?? I get this error when using it:java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.getString(BridgeResources.java:501)
    at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:334)
    at org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView.readAttrs(GaugeView.java:224)
    at org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView.<init>(GaugeView.java:170)
    at org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView.<init>(GaugeView.java:175)
    at .........

Comment: That's awesome. How do you customize it? like setting a different needle style?

Comment: It is not configured for gradle. How to use it with android project now?

Answer (score 18):

For anyone looking for simple gauge view I made a library that you can clone and use/modify for your needs.

[CustomGauge](https://github.com/pkleczko/CustomGauge)

[image]

Comment: nice library , but I need it only 180 degree how can I approach that

Comment: I used your library but it is showing an error in all `gauge:***` attributes. I added `xmlns:gauge="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` but still getting the errors. @pkleczko Can you say what is wrong?

Comment: Bad it is GPL licensed which is not possible for me.

Comment: @lschuetze - please feel free to use it for any purpose. Why GPL is not enough for you?

Comment: This is absolutely great! Thanks. I like it because it's simple but still looks good.

Comment: can you please answer @NirmalRaj question I used your library but it is showing an error in all gauge:*** attributes. ME to facing the same issue.

Comment: @Mann I was not able to resolve the error that I was having so I wrote my own code instead of using a library

Comment: @NirmalRaj hey nirmal, actually I taught I was tagging the author, asking the solution for his library. Anyhow I found a solution for it use it like `app:gaugeEndValue` instead of `gauge:EndValue`. it works.

Answer (score 13):

All other gauges you recommended have bugs and don't run fine on Kitkat and Lollipop. Also there is no Android Studio and gradle friendly library here.

Here's git repo for the more recent one updated for Lollipop you can use with Gradle:

- https://github.com/Sulejman/GaugeView

[image]

After you include library in your project add gaugelibrary to xml layout of your activity:

```
<io.sule.gaugelibrary.GaugeView
 android:id="@+id/gauge_view"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#ffffff"
 gauge:showOuterShadow="false"
 gauge:showOuterRim="false"
 gauge:showInnerRim="false"
 gauge:needleWidth="0.010"
 gauge:needleHeight="0.40"
 gauge:scaleStartValue="0"
 gauge:scaleEndValue="100"
 />
```

This will show static gauge without needle. To instantiate needle with random animation you need to do that in activity class file. See how it's done here:

```
package io.sule.testapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.Random;

import io.sule.gaugelibrary.GaugeView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private GaugeView mGaugeView;
   private final Random RAND = new Random();

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      mGaugeView = (GaugeView) findViewById(R.id.gauge_view);
      mTimer.start();
   }


   private final CountDownTimer mTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

      @Override
      public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {
         mGaugeView.setTargetValue(RAND.nextInt(101));
      }

      @Override
      public void onFinish() {}
   };
}
```

This will instantiate needle and make it animate moving to random values.

Comment: Hey @sulejman this library has the minSdk version set to 21, that's a little too high for my application so when I import it to my application with minSdk version of 9 I get merger errors at the time of build, can you please set the minSdk to a lower version or propose a work-around?

Comment: You can set it on your own, but I'm not sure if it's going to actually work with 9 level, it think it works from 13, but is just set to 21. Download library from git and play around :)

Comment: can we apply negative value to this GaugeView. I tried but not success

Comment: @Mehrdad I am sorry, I was inactive for long time, if it helps, I updated link.

Comment: Does it support negative values  ?

Comment: And is it free to use ?

Comment: where is the dependency?

Answer (score 5):

I made this one a while ago. Feel free to clone and modify. (It takes some ideas from the old [Vintage Thermometer](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/).)

[github.com/Pygmalion69/Gauge](https://github.com/Pygmalion69/Gauge)

[image]

It can easily be added to your Gradle project:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://www.jitpack.io'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.Pygmalion69:Gauge:1.1'
}
```

The views are declared in XML:

```
<de.nitri.gauge.Gauge
    android:id="@+id/gauge1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    gauge:labelTextSize="42"
    gauge:maxValue="1000"
    gauge:minValue="0"
    gauge:totalNicks="120"
    gauge:valuePerNick="10"
    gauge:upperText="Qty"
    gauge:lowerText="@string/per_minute" />
```

Here's an example of setting the values programmatically:

```
    final Gauge gauge1 = (Gauge) findViewById(R.id.gauge1);
    final Gauge gauge2 = (Gauge) findViewById(R.id.gauge2);
    final Gauge gauge3 = (Gauge) findViewById(R.id.gauge3);
    final Gauge gauge4 = (Gauge) findViewById(R.id.gauge4);

    gauge1.moveToValue(800);

    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("GaugeDemoThread");
    thread.start();
    Handler handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            gauge1.moveToValue(300);
        }
    }, 2800);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            gauge1.moveToValue(550);
        }
    }, 5600);

    HandlerThread gauge3Thread = new HandlerThread("Gauge3DemoThread");
    gauge3Thread.start();
    Handler gauge3Handler = new Handler(gauge3Thread.getLooper());
    gauge3Handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (float x = 0; x <= 6; x += .1) {
                float value = (float) Math.atan(x) * 20;
                gauge3.moveToValue(value);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    gauge4.setValue(333);
```

Answer (score 4):

On this site you will find some free customizable gauges.

[ScComponents](http://www.sccomponents.com/)

Very easy to install and well documented.
For example you can have for free something like this in 5 minutes following the instruction below.

[image]

Go on the above linked website. Click the GR004 and after the popup appear click on "Download for FREE".
The library will downloaded, unzip and follow the instruction to install the library (aar file) inside your Android project.

Write this code in your XML layout and your gauge will done:

```
<com.sccomponents.gauges.gr004.GR004
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You have many XML options to customize it:

- sccAnimDuration
- sccEnableTouch
- sccInverted
- sccFontName
- sccLabelsSizeAdjust
- sccMajorTicks
- sccMaxValue
- sccMinorTicks
- sccMinValue
- sccShowContour
- sccShowLabels
- sccText
- sccValue

And the related function by coding.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether the late answer is going to help or not. I also came to the same situation where i want to use a gauge to  visualize data, since gauge is not given as widget in android, as a enthusiast i went for libraries like above which can be found through various links in the Internet, although it was quite helpful(thanks to the wonderful authors of it..) i find myself difficult to visualize the during certain situations, so another solution what i have done is for my app is i integreated the JavaScript gauges into my android application.
You can do that by the following steps

1. Create an asset folder in our project-[look this link](http://code2care.org/2015/create-assets-folder-in-android-studio/) and you will see how to create an asset folder if someone don't knows about it.
2. Next one is you have design an html page on how your page sholud look like, for eg- header,no.of guages etc... and place it in the folder asset.
3. There are many sites which provide the guages like [This is one site](http://justgage.com/) or you can browse other sites and take whatever you feel cool...!!
   take it all including .js files and place it in the asset folder.
4. Android provides a class for handling webiview called **"WebViewClient"** you can browse more to know more about it in internet
5. This is sample code for viewing the webview content..

   web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
       progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

   ```
   web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

     web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
               web.post(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/fonts/guage.html");
                   }
               });
   ```

The above for loading the html & javscript.

```
 public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

This the webview class

1. You can also send data from activity to html page.. [Refer This link](http://pavan2pyati.blogspot.in/2013/12/android-native-data-to-hmtl-page.html)

Kindly read through all, corrections are welcomed..!!

Comment: A roundabout approach, but one that works nonetheless. Still, with Android dev, custom views always perform and look better than HTML/JS inside a webview

Comment: Well, am a beginner and had less time.... Thanks @mix3d can you elaborate your answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this : [Sample Project](https://github.com/jignesh13/SpeedoMeter)

It can easily be added to your Gradle project:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://www.jitpack.io'
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.jignesh13.speedometer:speedometer:1.0.0'
}
```

The views are declared in XML:

```xml
    <com.jignesh13.speedometer.SpeedoMeterView
        android:id="@+id/speedometerview"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.453"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:backimage="@android:color/black"
        app:needlecolor="#fff"
        app:removeborder="false"
        app:linecolor="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.079" />
```

Comment: This one is cool, but the top speed and graduations are all hard coded