# how to create a Speed-O-Meter chart or half moon like graphs in android with different data

Tags: java, android

I want to create a graphics or graph like a half moon  as follows-

[image: Half Moon Graph]

I am new into graphics design in android and even new to android.
Any suggestion will be great.
I have already followed the android's graphics tutorial. Need more pointers to achieve the same.

I've found the link https://code.google.com/p/charts4j/source/browse/tags/v1.2/example/com/googlecode/charts4j/GoogleOMeterExample.java#50
 but need some more accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Guage view. There is already a post on that topic u can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551295/simple-gauge-view-like-speedmeter-in-android)

The Git for that porject is [here](https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView)

Just download the project and add it to yours. Then use the guage view in your layout and also define the parameters like `setTargetValue();` and whatever else you want

I have successfully implemented it in my project. So feel free to ask me any doubts.

Thanks to evelyne24 (Github) for creating Guage view.

[The Guage view looks like this](https://github-camo.global.ssl.fastly.net/a718f2a163b178d58249d7d62b751f5cf72a7c5d/687474703a2f2f676f6f2e676c2f4875374f75)