# Creating a gauge

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a gauge. I have a PNG of a blank gauge and a second one, exactly the same size showing the needle. My idea is to overlay the needle on top of the gauge and then rotate it depending on the value I wish to display.
I'm having trouble placing one image on top of the other. Does anyone know how to do this? The image is within a LinearLayout.

Comment: Option 1: extend Image view and develop your own control

Comment: Option 2: Use gauge image as background of ImageView and put needle as src... Option 3.... Take frame layout or relative layout ... put both images view 1. gauge and 2. needle

Comment: This will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551295/simple-gauge-view-like-speedmeter-in-android

Comment: https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView

Comment: https://github.com/pkleczko/CustomGauge

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RelativeLayout for this.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/needle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/needle" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cluster"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/cluster" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rpmVal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
                android:text="00000"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="60sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView23"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/rpmVal"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rpmVal"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rpmVal"
                android:text="RPM"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView24"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/rpmVal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView23"
                android:text="x100 rpm"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

This setup shoul look like this:
[image: null]

I hope I could help ^^

Comment: Thank you. This is a project I finished about 18 months ago by using a custom gauge that I found somewhere else. I'm actually planning to rewrite it soon so I will experiment with your solution then.