# How to make such kind of view

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have to make this kind of view, where a dot will display on semicircle based upon the score. I have the image of semicircle and the dot.
Kindly help

[image]

Comment: Did you find something? I am searching for the same view. Maybe this one could help: https://github.com/Shinelw/ColorArcProgressBar

Answer (score 3):

**Get your expectation oriented result from the folowing source link then you have to customize your own layout view**

> Source: https://github.com/anastr/SpeedView
>
> https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-speedometer-tutorial/
>
> [Simple gauge view like speedmeter in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551295/simple-gauge-view-like-speedmeter-in-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

You have to use this way

Gradle file:

```
compile 'com.github.anastr:speedviewlib:1.1.7'
```

xml file:

```
<com.github.anastr.speedviewlib.SpeedView
        android:id="@+id/speedView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

in java Code:

```
SpeedView speedometer = findViewById(R.id.speedView);
speedometer.speedTo(60);
```

or

```
// move to 50 Km/s with loading Duration = 2 sec 
speedometer.speedTo(50, 2000);
```

Comment: It's not working, Automatically showing random movement , Not following given value, even if I'm setting 0, but pin moving MIN to MAX randomly.